# Linq - selection item from ListView

Tags: c#, linq, listview

How could I select all information about selected item, not only first column but all ?

For the first column I just need :

```
ListView.Items.AddRange(ListData
    .Where(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text) || i.ID.StartsWith(searchBox.Text))
    .Select(c => new ListViewItem(c.ID))
    .ToArray());
```

Lets say that next columns are : `Name`, `LastName`

I know that I have to use Linq segment which looks like :

```
(...).Select(c => {  })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove for a while LINQ from the field, and answer yourself "what should I do to add a single ListViewItem to my ListView, populating Column name and LastName too?"

Comment: Well, the first column is an item and next column is subitem from this item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ListViewItem ctor that accept an array of string (where elements after the first are the subitems)

Assuming your class has the properties `LastName` and `Name`

```
ListView.Items.AddRange(ListData.Where(i =>    
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text) 
            || i.ID.StartsWith(searchBox.Text))
            .Select(c => new ListViewItem // this part
               (
                 new string[]{c.ID, c.Name, c.LastName}
               )).ToArray());
```

If the creation of a single ListViewItem get more complicated, consider using a funcion:

```
ListView.Items.AddRange(ListData.Where(i =>    
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text) 
            || i.ID.StartsWith(searchBox.Text))
            .Select(c => CreateListViewItemFromElement(c)).ToArray());

private ListViewItem CreateListViewItemFromElement(MyClass element)
{
// handle the element to create a "complete" ListViewItem with subitems
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(c.ID);
    ....
    return item;
}
```

(actually, I would use the latter in every case, it's much more readable to me)

Comment: Thanks! I will do this maybe in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Just init all properties that you need in `.Select()` method line this:

```
ListView.Items.AddRange(ListData.Where(i =>    
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBox.Text) 
            || i.ID.StartsWith(searchBox.Text))
            .Select(c => new ListViewItem // this part
               {
                   Name = c.ID.ToString(),
                   Text = c.Name + " " + c.LastName
               }).ToArray());
```

Maby you want to fill different properties, so fill freee to change this part as you want.

Comment: But I need them not as a string, but each value in the correct column.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [`ListViewItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx) class has 22 (!) [constructor overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.%23ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true), so you can use any of them that supports passing `string[] items`, for instance [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faw83h4f(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
.Select(c => new ListViewItem(new string[] { c.ID, c.Name, c.LastName }))
```